# Foreign key to access data Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to display `role_title` in template using user_role

```
  class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user_role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
              return self.user.username

    class Roles(models.Model):
        role_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        role_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('role-create')

        def __str__(self) : 
            return self.role_title
```

Comment: Please add code where you render your template and do you pass any context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. Like:

For `UserDetailView` template:

```
# View

class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    ...

# In Template

{{ object.userprofile.user_role.role_title }}
```

For `UserProfileDetailView`:

```
class UserProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = UserProfile
    ...

# In Template

{{ object.user_role.role_title }}
```

And for any logged in user:

```
{{ user.userprofile.user_role.role_title }}
```